# "Undefined control sequence" in empty line under \maketitle and moving from line to line when code changes

Tags: titles

I get the error "Undefined control sequence." in the empty line under \maketitle. The funny thing is, when I delete the empty line, the error jumps to the next command below (which is \pagenumbering). When I make that command a comment, the error jumps down one command.

So it looks to me like this error is not linked to the single commands (which btw. have been included by \usepackage) but rather point to some problem on a higher level. Any ideas what that could be? THANK YOU!

This is my title and below the document where it is included:

```
%======================================================================
%   Titelseite 
%======================================================================
%   $Date:$
%   $Revision:$
%   Matthias Kupfer
%======================================================================

%%======================================================================
%% Titelkopf
%%======================================================================
\titlehead{
    \vspace*{-1.5cm}
    % Schriftfamilie wie alle Überschriften, aber nicht fett
    \usekomafont{disposition}\mdseries 
    \begin{center}
        \raisebox{-1ex}{}\\
        \hrulefill \\[1em]
    %   {\Large\dcdepart}\\[0.5em] 
        \dcprof
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{1.5cm}
}

%%======================================================================
%% Subjekt
%%======================================================================
\subject{\bf\Huge\dcsubject}


%%======================================================================
%% Titel
%%======================================================================
\title{\sf\Large
    \dctitle
    \\
    \dcsubtitle
    \bigskip
    \\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Bilder/photo_2019-07-24_16-09-21.jpg}
}
%%======================================================================
%% Autor des Dokumentes
%%======================================================================
\author{\dcauthorfirstname~\dcauthorlastname}   
%%======================================================================
%% Ort, Datum
%%======================================================================
\date{\dcdate
}


%%======================================================================
%% maketitle
%%======================================================================

\maketitle

%%======================================================================
%%      Inhaltsverzeichnis
%%======================================================================
%%\cleardoubleemptypage
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\pdfbookmark{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents


%%======================================================================
%%      Ende
%%======================================================================
%%\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

```
%======================================================================
%   Vorlage
%======================================================================
%   $Id$
%   Matthias Kupfer
%======================================================================
%   Documentclass
%======================================================================
\documentclass[
%   draft,          % Entwurfsmodus: Bilder als Rahmen,
                % Überlängen werden deutlich markiert
%   10pt,           % 
    11pt,           % KOMA default
%   12pt,           % 
    a4paper,        % DIN A4
    twoside,        % Zweiseitig
    german,         %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Die folgenden Befehle stammen aus dem KOMA Paket
    headsepline,        % Linie unter der Kopfzeile 
%   headnosepline,      %
%   foodsepline,        % Linie über Fussnote   
    footnosepline,      %
    automark,       % Kolumnentitel lebendig
%   bigheadings,        % default: Überschriften gross setzen
    normalheadings,     % Überschriften normal setzen
%   smallheadings,      % Überschriften eher klein setzen
%   pointlessnumbers,   % Keinen Punkt hinter die letzte Zahl 
                % eines Kapitels (auch bei Anhang)
%   chapterprefix,      % Kapiteluberschriften "Kapitel"
    appendixprefix,     % Anhang
%   openright,      % Kapitel auf der rechten (ungeraden) Seite 
                % anfangen lassen
    openany,        % 
%   cleardoublestandard,    %
    cleardoubleplain,   %
%   cleardoubleempty,   %
    abstracton,     %
    idxtotoc,       % Index soll im Inhaltsverzeichnis auftauchen
    liststotoc,     %
    bibtotoc,       %
%   parskip,        % parskip-, parskip*, parskip+
%   halfparskip,        % halfparskip-, halfparskip* und halfparskip+
%   DIVclassic,
    BCOR8mm,        %%?? Bindungskorrektur: 
                % BCOR<Breite des Bindungsverlustes> 
]{scrreprt} 

%======================================================================
%   Bearbeitung sowohl mit LaTeX als auch mit pdfLaTeX ermoeglichen
%======================================================================
%\newif\ifpdf 
    %\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined 
    %\pdffalse          % we are not running pdflatex 
%\else 
    %\pdfoutput=1           % we are running pdflatex 
    %\pdftrue 
%\fi


%======================================================================
%   Verwendete Pakete
%======================================================================

%\usepackage{babel}     % Sprachen

%% Latex mit deutschen Umlauten:
%% http://www.cs.albany.edu/~herrmann/latex_umlaute/
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % Eingabe von ü,ö,ä,ß erlaubt 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % EC-Schriften verwenden (vs. DC) da 8-Bit
                % EC-Schriften als T1-kodierten CM-Schriften
                % European/Ext.-Computer-Modern-(EC)-Schriften
                % Umlaute, Anführungszeichen ...
                % => Umlauten koennen richtig getrennt werden
                % FAQ 5.3.2

\usepackage{ae,aecompl}     % virtuelle-CM-Fonts
                % da EC nicht als PostScript-(Type-1) verfuegbar
                % => keine echten Umlaute im PDF-Dokumen 
                %(Problem bei Suche)
                % By loading the ae package (\usepackage{ae}), 
                % you loose some characters as mentioned in 
                % README. 
                % The package aecompl by Denis Roegel restores
                % these characters which are taken from the ec 
                % fonts. If you use pdftex, you will get these 
                % characters as bitmaps, but this might be 
                % better than not having them at all.

%\usepackage{times, mathptm}    % TimesNewRoman Schrift (Acrobat Reader Fonts), 
                % dazu braucht man auch den entsprechenden 
                % Zeichensatz für den Math-Mode
%\usepackage{pslatex}       % ? mathematische Formeln mit Standard 
                % Postscript Fonts gesetzt
            % Paket     Roman         Serifenlos  Typewriter
%\usepackage{times} % -----------------------------------------------
            % times     Times         Helvetica   Courier
            % palatino  Palatino      Helvetica   Courier
            % newcent   NewCenturySch AvantGarde  Courier
            % bookman   Bookman       AvantGarde  Courier
            % Diese Schriften sind die Standard-PostScript-Schriften
            % und in jedem Drucker verfügbar

\usepackage{
%   german,         % Deutsche Trennungen (ALTE Rechtschreibung), 
                % Anführungsstriche und mehr 
    ngerman,        % Deutsche Trennungen (NEUE Rechtschreibung), 
                % Anführungsstriche und mehr
                %
%   acronym,        % Verwaltung von Abkuerzungen
    bibgerm,        % Deutsche Bibliographie 
    calc,           % Erweiterung der arithmetischen Funktionen in 
                % LaTeX
                % wird verwendet um Titelseite zu zentrieren
    color,          % im Laufenden Text einfach mit \color{Farbe) zwischen den 
                % Farben umschalten, wobei Farbe einfach 
                % durch z.B. red, blue, black etc. ersetzt wird
                % \textcolor{farbe){Text)
%   epigraph,       % Zitat am Kapitelanfang
%   fancyhdr,       % Kopf- und Fußzeilen von Dokumenten frei 
                % gestalten
    fancybox,       % shadowbox, doublebox, ovalbox, Ovalbox 
    fancyvrb,       % verbatim Erweiterung:
    float,          % Positionierung von Gleitobjekten genau an der Stelle, wo man
                % 'figure'- oder 'table'-Umgebung die 
                % Positionierung [H] gesetzt werden
%   glosstex,       % Glossar und Abkürzungsverzeichnis
    mdwlist,        % compact list: itemize* ..
    scrdate,        % \todaysname 
    scrtime,        % \thistime
    scrpage2,       % Kopf- und Fußzeilen flexibel gestalten
                %
%   moreverb,       % verbatim-ähnlich: boxedverbatim, listing
%   verbatim,       % Darstellung von "Text, wie er eingegeben wird"
                %
%   lscape,         % Erstellt eine um 90% gedrehte *neue* Seite
%   textcomp,       % Sonderzeichen
%   booktabs,       % Tabellenlinien
%   longtable,      % Tabellen > 1 Seite
%   supertabular,       % Tabellen > 1 Seite
    tabularx,       % Blocksatzspalten
%   ltxtable,       % tabularx + longtable
%   multicol,       % mehrspaltige Zeilen
%   varioref,       % einheitliche Verweise
%   endnotes,       % Fussnoten -> Endnoten
%   rotating,       % sidewaystable und sidewaysfigure
%   natbib,         % Bibliographie ohne Klammer etc.
%   marvosym,       % Euro etc.
}

%\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{wasysym}

%\usepackage[german, first, bottomafter]{draftcopy}

%\usepackage{setspace}  % Durchschuß, Zeilenabstand
%\doublespace       % doppelzeilig oder
%\onehalfspacing    % anderthalbzeilig

% Für schöne Darstellung von Algorithmen
%\usepackage[german, algoruled, algochapter]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
%\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithmus}

%======================================================================
%   Bilder, Links
%======================================================================

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{../img/}}   % Angabe der Pfade, wo die Grafiken liegen; 
                % mehrere Pfade sind möglich

\usepackage{thumbpdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}



%======================================================================
%   user.sty
%======================================================================

\usepackage{user}   % Makros in user.sty 
            % \epsinc{bild.eps}{scale=1}{Bildunterschrift}
            % \missing{Beweis fehlt noch}
            % \comment{Ein Kommentar}

%======================================================================
%   Einstellungen
%======================================================================

%\typearea{11}      % Satzspiegel neu konstruieren (KOMA)
            %      10pt 11pt 12pt 
            % DIV : 8   10   12  

\pagestyle{scrheadings} % Standart  Kopf- und Fußzeile
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\small\scshape}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
%\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%\sloppy        % weniger Worttrennungen, größere Wortabstände
\fussy          % viele Worttrennungen, "schönere" Wortabstände

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%\flushbottom           % Ausrichtung der Seitenenden jeweils auf 
                % gleicher Höhe

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%\sloppypar     % Das hier relaxt die Einstellungen zum Wortabstand 
            % extrem. Damit ragen keine Worte über den rechten 
            % Zeilenabstand hinaus. Dafür muß stärker auf
            % Wortabstand geachtet werden, der kann dann ziemlich 
            % groß werden. Man erhält aber keine Meldung mehr 
            % über underfull boxes.

%Hiermit kann man das gleiche mit weniger Holzhammer erreichen:
%\setlength{\tolerance}{2000}           % Strafpunkt für Zeilenumbruch
%\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3pt}     % Soweit dürfen einzelne Worte mehr 
                    % auseinandergezogen werden
%\setlength{\hfuzz}{1pt}                % Macht den rechten Rand um bis zu 1pt 
                    % flatterig.

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%Vermeiden einzelner Zeilen am Ende einer Seite oder oben auf einer neuen Seite
%\clubpenalty10000
%\widowpenalty10000

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% neue Umgebungen für verwendete Sätze und Beispiele
\newtheorem{bsp}{Beispiel}[chapter]
\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[chapter]

%======================================================================
%   includeonly
%======================================================================

\includeonly{       % Gibt an, welche Dateien der include-Befehl 
            % tatsächlich einfuegen darf.
  metadaten     % Variablen setzen
  ,titel        % Titelseite, Zusammenfassung und Inhaltsverzeichnis
% Alle per include einzulesenden Dateien müssen hier angegeben sein!
  ,anleitung        % Anleitung zur Nutzung der Vorlage
}

% Aufteilung der Arbeit in folgende Bestandteile in angeg. Reihenfolge
%
% Titelseite
% Bibliographische Beschreibung (Rückseite der Titelseite)
% (Aufgabenstellung)
% Danksagung
% Abstract
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
% Tabellenverzeichnis
% Abbildungsverzeichnis
% Einleitung
% Inhalt
% Zusammenfassung/Ausblick
% (Verzeichnis verwendeter Terme)
% Glossar (Abkürzungsverzeichnis)
% (Index)
% Literaturverzeichnis
% (Thesen)
% (Selbstständigkeitserklärung)
% Anhänge


%======================================================================
% * *   T E X T    S T A R T S    H E R E   * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
%======================================================================

\begin{document}
\include{metadaten} % Variablen, \hypersetup, etc.

%======================================================================
%   Titelseite (Zusammenfassung und Inhaltsverzeichnis)
%======================================================================

\include{titel} % Titelseite, Zusammenfassung 
        % Inhaltsverzeichnis
        % Abkuerzungsverzeichnis
        % -> danach Seitennummerierung bei 1

%======================================================================
%   Inhalt per include
%======================================================================

\include{anleitung} % Datei, welche die Anleitung zur Nutzung der 
            % Vorlage enthält


%======================================================================
%   Glossar
%======================================================================

%\manualmark
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossar}
%\markboth{Glossar}{Glossar}
%\def\glossaryname{Glossar}
%\printglosstex(glo)
%\cleardoublepage

%======================================================================
%   Literaturverzeichnis
%======================================================================
%\manualmark
%\markboth{Literaturverzeichnis}{Literaturverzeichnis}
%\bibliographystyle{user}
%\bibliography{literatur}
%\cleardoublepage

%======================================================================
%   Thesen
%======================================================================
%\chapter{Thesen}
%\include{thesen}

%======================================================================
%   Selbstständigkeitserklärung
%======================================================================
%\chapter*{Selbstständigkeitserklärung}0

%Hiermit erkläre ich, daß ich die vorliegende Arbeit
%selbstständig angefertigt, nicht anderweitig zu Prüfungszwecken vorgelegt und
%keine anderen als die angegebenen Hilfsmittel verwendet habe. Sämtliche 
%wissentlich verwendete Textausschnitte, Zitate oder Inhalte anderer Verfasser 
%wurden ausdrücklich als solche gekennzeichnet.\\[2ex]
%\dcplace, den \dcdate\\[6ex]
%\flushleft
%\newlength\us
%\settowidth{\us}{-\dcauthorfirstname~\dcauthorlastname-}
%\begin{tabular}{p{\us}}\hline
%\centering\footnotesize \dcauthorfirstname~\dcauthorlastname
%\end{tabular}

%======================================================================
%   Anhang
%======================================================================


%\part*{Anhang}
\cleardoublepage
\appendix
%\include{anhanga}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. First of all, it would be great if you could trim your example down to the smallest piece of code needed to reproduce the error. Your current example also includes several files that we don't have (`user.sty`, `metadata.tex`, `anleitung.tex`), so an example that doesn't relied on those would be better.  Finally, if you look at the `.log` file you might find the entire error message, which will tell you exactly which macro/control sequence triggered it. It will be the last macro on the first line of the error.

Comment: Thank you, I think I found the relevant part in the log:

`
! Undefined control sequence.
\@titlehead ...ex}{}\\ \hrulefill \\[1em] \dcprof 
                                                  \end {center} \vspace *{1....
l.58 
     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
`

Will keep digging...

Comment: Comments doesn't preserve line breaks, is `\dcprof` at the end of first line?

Comment: Cool, you found the problem. The definition \dcprof was commented out in the metadata. When I uncomment it, the error is gone.

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped me understand that the variables are commands and I should check them as well not just package imports.

Comment: Off topic: your template seems to be very old. There are obsolete options (see the warnings in the log file) and deprecated packages: eg. `ae`, `german`, `ngerman`, `scrpage2`. Avoid the deprecated old font command `\bf`.